# How to solve UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported? Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I´m trying to run this code with Node.js but I always get the same error:

```
(node:9092) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported
(node:9092) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I´ve tried many things like pasting the whole path or deleting everything but  but I have no Idea, what my mistake is. It doesn´t matter if I remove the `d3.csv(..)` method or the `csvWriter`or both together. I tested it with and without then/catch or Promise but nothing changes. I tried to run a simple code with only `console.log("test");` and this works, so it´s not Node.js that doesn´t work. This is my code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const d3 = require('d3');
global.fetch = require("node-fetch");

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    d3.csv(".\\dat\\Meteorite_Landings.csv")}).then(function(data) {

        //parse strings to numbers
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            var date;
            if (d.year){
                date = new Date (d.year);}
                else{
                    date = null;
                }        
            d["mass (g)"] = +d["mass (g)"];
            d.reclat = +d.reclat;
            d.reclong = +d.reclong;
            d.date = date;
            d.year = date? date.getYear() +1900 : null; 
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            assert.isNotOk(error);
        });
        console.log(data[0]);

        createTimeLineData(data);
        //createThemeRiver(data);
    });

function filterYear(data){
    /** Eliminate data without year */
    filteredData = [];
    data.forEach(function(item){
        if(item.year){
            filteredData.push(item);
        }
    });
    return filteredData;
}

function getAllYears(data){
    var yearArray=[];
    data.forEach((item)=>{ 
        /** creates array of all given years */
        if(0 > yearArray.indexOf(item.year)){
            yearArray.push(item.year);
            }
    });
    return yearArray;
}

function createTimeLineData(rawData){
    var data = filterYear(rawData);
    var yearArray = (getAllYears(data)).sort();

    csvWriter(yearArray);
}

function csvWriter(data){
    const createCsvWriter = require("csv-writer").createObjectCsvWriter;
    const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({path: 'trData.csv'});

    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    csvWriter.writeRecords(data)}).then(()=> console.log("success"))
    .catch((error) => {
        assert.isNotOk(error);
      });
}
```

Does anyone have an idea what i´m doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you wrapping your code into `new Promise((resolve, reject) => {` and then don't call resolve or reject? the way you use Promise is to return it from function and the use it with `fn().then()`

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not seem to use Promises in the expected way. Promises should be used to wrap async operations and should either call `resolve()` or `reject()` (and that determines if it enters the `then()` or `catch()` blocks of whoever is calling that Promise).

Some best practices when working with async code is to always return the value expected from your functions (even and especially when they are promises!), and to reduce the number of `catch` blocks, to avoid having your promise error being swallowed silently in the promise chain.

Considering that, change your code like below:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const d3 = require('d3');
global.fetch = require("node-fetch");

d3.csv(".\\dat\\Meteorite_Landings.csv")
    .then(function(data) {
        //parse strings to numbers
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            var date;
            if (d.year){
                date = new Date (d.year);}
            else{
                date = null;
            }
            d["mass (g)"] = +d["mass (g)"];
            d.reclat = +d.reclat;
            d.reclong = +d.reclong;
            d.date = date;
            d.year = date? date.getYear() +1900 : null; 
        });
        return data;
    }).then((data) => {
        return createTimeLineData(data);
    }).then(() => console.log("success"))
    .catch((error) => {
       assert.isNotOk(error);
    });

function filterYear(data){
    /** Eliminate data without year */
    filteredData = [];
    data.forEach(function(item){
        if(item.year){
            filteredData.push(item);
        }
    });
    return filteredData;
}

function getAllYears(data){
    var yearArray=[];
    data.forEach((item)=>{ 
        /** creates array of all given years */
        if(0 > yearArray.indexOf(item.year)){
            yearArray.push(item.year);
        }
    });
    return yearArray;
}

function createTimeLineData(rawData){
    var data = filterYear(rawData);
    var yearArray = (getAllYears(data)).sort();
    return csvWriter(yearArray);
}

function csvWriter(data){
    const createCsvWriter = require("csv-writer").createObjectCsvWriter;
    const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({path: 'trData.csv'});
    return csvWriter.writeRecords(data);
}
```

**UPDATE**:
What is really breaking your app is described in the error message: `TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported`, so the problem is that you're using a relative path when reading your CSV but D3 uses `node-fetch` to read the CSV file and node-fetch [does not support relative URLs](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch/issues/75).

You may want to try wrapping the URL with `path.resolve()`, like in `d3.csv(path.resolve('/dat/Meteorite_Landings.csv'))` (also, don't forget to require path before, with `const path = require('path');`).

Comment: thank you for the effort! yes I see that I´ve used the Promises in the wrong way. But the Error doesn´t disappear. Neither with your code, nor with removing all promises nor with removing the filereading in general...

Comment: Seems like node-fetch (used by d3.csv) does not support relative URLs. Please check my new updated answer!

Comment: When I run the code in Browser, I get to the line console.log(data[0]). In general, the code was working in Browser
to your Update: Yes, it was my first intention to change the path and even remove the whole filereading part. Error stays the same

Comment: make sure to load the URL module, like `const URL = require('url').URL;`

Comment: Ah yes, thanks, that does it with the URL! But now I get the same old error again...

Comment: I found out the Problem lies in the const d3 = require('d3'); When I remove this line, the error disappears. but i need d3 and don´t know how to handle that..

Comment: Please try changing `csv()` to use `path.resolve()`, like in `const path = require('path');` and then `d3.csv(path.resolve('/dat/Meteorite_Landings.csv'))`